# (Vue.js) component data binding.. ( <tag> )

Tags: vue.js

Here is the result I want:

> **strong~~**
>
> blah blah

---

But currently my result is:

> `<b>strong~~<b><br/>blah blah`

---

And this is my code

```html
<script>
import Child from './component/Child.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'Child' : Child
  },
  data() {
    return{
      imgs: [
        {
          thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/img1.jpg'),
          description: '<b>strong~~<b><br/>blah blah'
        },
        {
          thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/img2.jpg'),
          description: '<b>strong~~<b><br/>blah blah'
        },
        {
          thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/img3.jpg'),
          description: '<b>strong~~<b><br/>blah blah'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does your template look like? You probably just need to use `v-html`, eg `<div v-html="img.description"></div>` ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: Show us how you bind `imgs[x].description` into the template, please

Comment: What @Phil said, and/or you are missing the closing `</b>` tag?

Comment: @YomS. There is a typo in the question. But in a real project it's '</ b>'. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: @Phil I solved the problem using 'v-html'. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @acdcjunior I solved the problem using 'v-html'. Thank you for your comment :)